# How to represent magnitude for mass in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

```
// SI units
enum Magnitude : Measurement {
    case Milli = Measurement(-3, "ml")
    case Centi = Measurement(-2, "cl")
    case Desi = Measurement(-1, "dl")
    case Gram = Measurement(0, "g")
    case Kilo = Measurement(3,"kg")
}


class Measurement {

    let magnitude : Int
    let shorthandName : String

    init(magnitude: Int, shorthandName: String) {
        self.magnitude = magnitude
        self.shorthandName = shorthandName
    }

}
```

I am implementing a converter as a part of an app. I've started with converting between the different magnitudes of mass. I was thinking its nice to have the Magnitude as an enum, strongly connected to its short hand name. But Swift does not let me have an enum with objects, because of the raw value needs to be a literal. Anyone know a more clever way of representing the connection between magnitude, its shorthand name and converting between the units?

Comment: Double check your enumeration labels and shorthand names. Desi is deci. 'ml', 'cl', and 'dl' are measurements of volume (liter). They should be 'm', 'c', and 'd' respectively. See http://www.nist.gov/pml/wmd/metric/prefixes.cfm

Comment: Thats true, i have an example for mass and one for volume so i mixed them when creating the example. Thanks for pointing out the correct terms!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to specify the unit of the mass with a `String` perhaps you could use `String` to represent the shorthand name and variables to give you more information about the unit, such as `magnitude`. Here's an example:

**1. `MassUnit`**

```
enum MassUnit: String {
    case Milligrams = "mg"
    case Grams      = "g"
    case Kilos      = "kg"
    case Tons       = "t"

    var magnitude: Int {
        let mag: Int

        switch self {
            case .Milligrams: mag = -3
            case .Grams     : mag =  0
            case .Kilos     : mag =  3
            case .Tons      : mag =  6
        }

        return mag
    }


    static func ordersOfMagnitudeFrom(unit1: MassUnit, to unit2: MassUnit) -> Int {
        return unit1.magnitude - unit2.magnitude
    }
}

extension MassUnit: Printable {
    var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

**2. Then, for storing actual masses you could use a `Struct`, which could also handle the conversions. For example:**

```
struct Mass {
    var value : Double
    var unit  : MassUnit

    static func convertMass(mass: Mass, toUnit unit: MassUnit) -> Mass {
        let ordersOfMagnitude = MassUnit.ordersOfMagnitudeFrom(mass.unit, to: unit)

        let multipler = pow(10.0, Double(ordersOfMagnitude))

        return Mass(value: mass.value * multipler, unit: unit)
    }

    //  Returns an optional Mass because we can't know for sure 
    //  unitString will represent a MassUnit.
    static func convertMass(mass: Mass, toUnit unitString: String) -> Mass? {
        if let unit = MassUnit(rawValue: unitString) {
            return convertMass(mass, toUnit: unit)
        }

        return nil
    }
}

extension Mass {
    init?(value: Double, _ unitString: String) {
        if let unit = MassUnit(rawValue: unitString) {
            self = Mass(value: value, unit: unit)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Mass : Printable {
    var description: String {
        return "\(value) \(unit)"
    }
}
```

**3. Then you can use the masses and units:**

```
if let mass = Mass(value: 1, "kg"),
   let convertedMass = Mass.convertMass(mass, toUnit: "g") {

    println("\(mass) converted to \(MassUnit.Grams) equals \(convertedMass)")

    // Prints: 1.0 kg converted to g equals 1000.0 g
}
```

However if you use a `unitString` that isn't convertible to a `MassUnit` (either when creating or converting) `nil` will be returned. For example:

```
let mass = Mass(value: 1, "NotAUnit") // nil
```

Comment: Really good solution. Only problem is that i can't assign a Mass from a string shorthand. For example: Mass(string:"kg", value: 40)

Comment: In that case, perhaps the `raw value` of `MassUnit` could be changed to a `String` that represents the shorthand name and you could use a variable to get the magnitude. In this way you could use `MassUnit(rawValue: "kg")` to create a `MassUnit`?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you need, maybe you can combine an enumeration of SI unit scales and the example in the Computed Properties section of Apple Swift Programming Guide. In this simplistic scheme all of input measurements would be stored in the same units (grams in this example). Then you would convert to whatever units you needed in the output.

It is very readable.

```
enum SI {
    case kg
    case hg
    case dag
    case g
    case dg
    case cg
    case mg

    var scale: Double {
        switch self {
        case kg:  return    0.001
        case hg:  return    0.01
        case dag: return    0.1
        case g:   return    1.0
        case dg:  return   10.0
        case cg:  return  100.0
        case mg:  return 1000.0
        }
    }
}

extension Double {
    var kg:  Double {return self * 1000.0}
    var hg:  Double {return self *  100.0}
    var dag: Double {return self *   10.0}
    var g:   Double {return self}
    var dg:  Double {return self *    0.1}
    var cg:  Double {return self *    0.01}
    var mg:  Double {return self *    0.001}

    func convertTo(si: SI) ->  Double {return self * si.scale}
}
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using a dictionary? For example:

```
let magnitudes: [String: Double] = [
    "ml": -3,
    "cl": -2,
    "dl": -1,
    "g": 0,
    "kg": 3

]

// list all units:
println(", ".join(magnitudes.keys)) // kg, g, ml, cl, dl


// convert
func convert(from: String, to: String, value: Double) -> Double{
    let mag1 = __exp10(magnitudes[from]!)
    let mag2 = __exp10(magnitudes[to]!)
    return value * mag1 / mag2
}


let result = convert("dl", "ml", 3.0)
println(result) // 300.0
```