# How to adhere to protocol method with a Raw type in method argument?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

```
protocol Measurement {
     mutating func convert(#toUnit: String)
}

enum MassUnit : String {
    case Milligram = "mg"
}

enum VolumeUnit : String {
     case Milliliter = "ml"
}

struct Mass : Measurement {
     mutating func convert(#toUnit: MassUnit)
     // Build error: Does not adhere to 'Measurement'
}

struct Volume : Measurement {
     mutating func convert(#toUnit: VolumeUnit)
     // Build error: Does not adhere to 'Measurement'
}

func +<T: Measurement> (left:T, right:T) -> Measurement {
    let newRightValue  = right.convert(toUnit: left.unit)
    return T(quantity: left.quantity + newRightValue.quantity , unit: left.unit)
}
```

How can I make `Mass` adhere correctly to `Measurement`? What change in the `Measurement` protocol is needed to get it to work with enum of type `String`?

Question updated with more information about why the convert method signature should say something about the argument given. The code is part of an open source Unit framework i'm building called [Indus Valley](https://github.com/haaakon/Indus-Valley)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with your unit conversions, I advise not trying to use `String`s to represent the units when converting the way you've got setup above. That's going to make your code complicated with checking the `String` can be converted to its respective enum every time you want to make a conversion. Also, what if you want to use the a `MassUnit`/`VolumeUnit` instead of a `String`?

I would recommend using the a setup similar to what I've outlined below. It references my previous answer -  [How to represent magnitude for mass in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613994/how-to-represent-magnitude-for-mass-in-swift)

(Note - I've excluded anything to do with the volume because it's basically the same as the implementation for the mass)

I'd make the units like so:

```
protocol UnitProtocol {
    var magnitude: Int { get }

    init?(rawValue: String)
}

// Taken from my previous answer.
enum MassUnit: String, UnitProtocol, Printable {
    case Milligram = "mg"
    case Gram      = "g"

    var magnitude: Int {
        let mag: Int

        switch self {
            case .Milligram: mag = -3
            case .Gram     : mag =  0
        }

        return mag
    }

    var description: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}

// Not making this a method requirement of `UnitProtocol` means you've only got to 
// write the code once, here, instead of in every enum that conforms to `UnitProtocol`.
func ordersOfMagnitudeFrom<T: UnitProtocol>(unit1: T, to unit2: T) -> Int {
    return unit1.magnitude - unit2.magnitude
}
```

Then I'd make the masses/volumes like so:

```
protocol UnitConstruct {
    typealias UnitType: UnitProtocol
    var amount: Double   { get }
    var unit  : UnitType { get }

    init(amount: Double, unit: UnitType)
}

struct Mass : UnitConstruct {
    let amount: Double
    let unit  : MassUnit
}
```

Now for the converting function! Using a global function means you don't need to rewrite the code for every type than conforms to `UnitConstruct`.

```
func convert<T: UnitConstruct>(lhs: T, toUnits unit: T.UnitType) -> T {
    let x = Double(ordersOfMagnitudeFrom(lhs.unit, to: unit))
    return T(amount: lhs.amount * pow(10, x), unit: unit)
}

// This function is for converting to different units using a `String`,
// as asked in the OP.
func convert<T: UnitConstruct>(lhs: T, toUnits unit: String) -> T? {
    if let unit = T.UnitType(rawValue: unit) {
        return convert(lhs, toUnits: unit)
    }

    return nil
}
```

You can then use the previous code like so:

```
let mass1 = Mass(amount: 1.0, unit: .Gram)
let mass2 = convert(mass1, toUnits: .Milligram) // 1000.0 mg

// Or, converting using Strings:
let right = convert(mass1, toUnits: "mg")       // Optional(1000.0 mg)
let wrong = convert(mass1, toUnits: "NotAUnit") // nil
```

Comment: Ah thanks, i'll try it. I can update the question with the reason i need MassUnit in the method signature as well

Comment: Updated now, so there is no way of ensuring that The protocol can go allright with enums? Just saying String might be confusing and unclear

Comment: Just updated my answer again :) I realised you wanted to convert using `String`s. The `UnitProtocol` has changed a bit and there's a new `convert` function. Examples at the end. Glad I could help though, good luck with your project!

Comment: Almost got it now. Only thing this solotuion does not give is the ability to have the convert methods on objects, which is preferrable.
For example `let kilogram = Mass(amount: 1, unit: .Kilo)
let gram = kilogram.convert(toUnit:Gram)`

Comment: Personally, I prefer using the global function. However if you want to use a instance method instead you could add a the method  `func convertMass(to: MassUnit) -> Mass {
        return convert(self, toUnits: to)
    }` Does that help? :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably confuse `enum MassUnit : String` with inheritance.

Contrary to `class ChildClass : ParentClass` which denotes that `ChildClass` inherits from `ParentClass`, `enum MassUnit : String` has a slightly different meaning, telling that **the rawType of the enum** is `String`, not that the enum inherits the String type.

So `MassUnit` is not of type String. You `MassUnit`'s `rawValue`s are of type String, but to access that you need to call the `rawValue` property of the enum to get that `String` equivalent.

Therefore, `mutating func convert(#toUnit: String)` and `mutating func convert(#toUnit: MassType)` are not compatible, as `MassType` is not a `String` itself. Only its `rawValue` is.

Comment: Yes, i confused them!