# Swift: maximum readability and extendability in example unit converter project

Tags: swift, methods

**Project outline:**

General purpose unit converter with categories such as temperature, mass, length etc. Each category consists of several units (such as Fahrenheit, Celsius etc...)

My approach so far is to have **a class for each type of unit** (Fahrenheit, Celsius etc...) conforming to the following protocol:

```
protocol Unit {
    var name: String { get }
    var category: String { get }

    func normaliseToSI(input: Double) -> Double
    func convertFromSI(input: Double) -> Double
}
```

The method `normaliseToSI()` **converts the unit** (say Celsius) **to a S.I. unit** for that category (i.e. Kelvin). The method `convertFromSI()` **converts a value in S.I. form to the unit of the class.**

Ideally I would like to be able to structure the code so that the process of adding a new unit (within an existing category) would be as simple as adding a new class.

I am just learning OO programming and I'm sure this is probably not a very good approach so would really appreciate any **feedback/advice** at this stage.

Comment: Here are two previous questions regarding converting units, maybe you'll find some inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613994/how-to-represent-magnitude-for-mass-in-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109996/how-to-adhere-to-protocol-method-with-a-raw-type-in-method-argument/30110459#30110459

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already did something very similar, although it doesn't have a strict notion of SI yet.

See https://github.com/fluidsonic/JetPack/tree/master/sources/measurement